# rel attribute in <a> in Rails 3 erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know that is there any rel attribute in <%= link_to_peramlink %> like  tag in html has.

For example:
in html
my link

I have <%= link_to_permalink article,"con", nil, "my link", "5m" %> in rails. Is there any rel attribute in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link_to_permalink` is not a standard Rails helper. A simple:

```
<%= link_to article.title, article %>
```

(you might have to adjust `article.title`) will get you a link to the article, assuming something like `resources :articles` is defined in `routes.rb`.

Setting a `rel` attribute is trivial:

```
<%= link_to article.title, article, :rel => 'nofollow' %>
```

or other attributes:

```
<%= link_to article.title, article, :rel => 'nofollow', :class => 'my-css-class' %>
```

Finally, I don't know what your `link_to_permalink` helper does, but you can use `to_param` to make seo-friendly permalinks: [see here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param). (This is the "Rails Way," if you know what I mean.)